# Fantasy book where you travel to different planets using books

Tags: story-identification

In the book you travel to different planets using books. I Cannot remember much else, just that some of the books were corroded making travel difficult.

Comment: this sounds a *lot* like *Myst*; could it have been one of the books based on the games?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - I had thought imaginarium geographica, but I don't remember the books being corroded.

Comment: some of the books in Myst were unfinished and/or damaged and it caused the words to degrade; I'm not sure that's quite the same.

Comment: We need some more information here. Roughly when did you read it? Was this part of a series? Do you remember anything about the covers or any characters? Was it aimed at any particular age group? What language was it in? Even tiny details can help us find this.

Comment: I agree with phantom. So far I've seen 3 different possible answers for your question, but we need more details to narrow it down.

Answer (score 7):

With the limited information you gave us, the ones that immediately come to mind are the *Myst* series of novels, which are based on the highly popular 90's video games.

There were three books in the series, and they told the backstory of the *Myst* games, about a dying race of people who were able to create new worlds by writing about them, then using the books to travel there. Over the course of the novels, the protagonists try to trap the antagonist in one of their created worlds by damaging the writing in the linking books, making them useless.

[image: Book of Atrus]
[image: Book of Ti'ana]
[image: Book of the D'ni]

Comment: And up to now I thought that the _Magic Ex Libris_ series (Hines) was an wholly original idea.

Comment: Well, technically whether writing a book causes a new world to be created or just creates a link to a pre-existing world is a big unanswered question in the series. Considering the question is crucial to the main character's development in The Book of Atrus, and the religious controversy that surrounds the question is vital to the plot of The Book of Ti'ana. There's persuasive evidence in favour of *both* possibilities in the series, so even though various characters can and do make up their minds, it's ultimately a matter of faith, rather than proof.